# NPM RUN DEV Freezing

Tags: laravel, npm, npm-install, breeze

I am trying to install laravel and breeze. Everything goes fine up to npm install. But when I run npm dev it freezes and nothing else happens. Below is what it says when it stops:

```
VITE v3.0.9  ready in 1434 ms

  ➜  Local:   http://127.0.0.1:5176/
  ➜  Network: use --host to expose

  LARAVEL v9.25.1  plugin v0.5.4

  ➜  APP_URL: http://localhost
```

Please! How do I resolve this?

UPDATE:
After running npm build, npm run dev still freezes. Below is the code.

```
npm run build

> build     
> vite build

vite v3.0.9 building for production...
✓ 119 modules transformed.
public/build/manifest.json             0.25 KiB
public/build/assets/app.c090eeea.css   186.93 KiB / gzip: 26.55 KiB
public/build/assets/app.aac2dc08.js    170.64 KiB / gzip: 57.15 KiB

amand@Amanda MINGW64 /c/laragon/www/patinoire
$ npm run dev

> dev
> vite

Port 5173 is in use, trying another one...
Port 5174 is in use, trying another one...

  VITE v3.0.9  ready in 1043 ms

  ➜  Local:   http://127.0.0.1:5175/
  ➜  Network: use --host to expose

  LARAVEL v9.25.1  plugin v0.5.4

  ➜  APP_URL: http://localhost
```

Comment: This is what the output is meant to look like after you've run `npm run dev`. Does it  update after you've changed a file?

Comment: npm run build and npm run dev again.

Comment: Yes, this is the output after I run npm dev. It freezes at this point and doesn't finish. I am starting a project so no files have been created or changed yet.

Comment: I did npm build and ran npm dev but the same output occurred.

Comment: I'm getting same error.. After running "npm run dev" it gets stuck in the same place. npm and node is installed...

Answer (score 1):

try

```
npm run build

npm run dev
```

i think it will work

Comment: npm run build worked fine but the problem persists with npm run dev:
```
$ npm run dev

> dev
> vite

Port 5173 is in use, trying another one...
Port 5174 is in use, trying another one...

  VITE v3.0.9  ready in 1043 ms

  ➜  Local:   http://127.0.0.1:5175/
  ➜  Network: use --host to expose

  LARAVEL v9.25.1  plugin v0.5.4

  ➜  APP_URL: http://localhost

```

Comment: please can you send the picture to your error

Comment: How do I send you the picture, please?

Comment: I edited the post and put the code there so it is easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me because I made a circular reference by mistake. I made a React component like this which is clearly invalid. After removing `TaskCard` from the `TaskCard` component, chrome stoped freezing. I wonder why there is no error showing up. I was able to even build by `npm run build`. Maybe because I used the same type name for props too. I corrected this as well.

```js
export const TaskCard = (props: TaskCard) => {
  const { key, title, onClick: onClick } = props

  return (
    <Card className=''>
      <p>{title}</p>
      <TaskCard key={key} onClick={onClick} title={title} />
    </Card>
  )
}
```